# (Shell Script) Variable not pass correctly when fetching value from file?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have this section of curl command inside my shell script which caused a error 500 repsonse from the server. However, this code works when I manually run the command.

```
curl -qgsSkH "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --no-progress-bar --header "Token: $authKey" -F "filename=@$compressedFileName" -F "options={\"application\":\"2\",\"timeout\":\"5000\"}" https://www.domain.com > results.txt
```

Anyone have any idea why?

**Edit:**
I did some manual debugging and found out that the issue is caused by the variable $authKey. This variable is fetched by the following code in my script.

```
# Get authentication key from FireEye AX response
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ ^SOME-PATTERN:[[:space:]](.*) ]]
    then
        authKey="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done <auth.txt
```

If I redefine this variable by using something like the following then the script will work.

```
authKey="TheAuthenticationKey"
```

But why is this happening? The earlier part where I pass the string from the file when I read it line by line is already passing the correct value (I double checked by echoing the output to a txt file).

**Edit**
I managed to drill down somemore. When I try to echo the value of the token to a file and add " to the start and the end of the string I got this result.

```
"X-FeApi-Token: IDR+jxU1kB5ZpXsRNAgqfjTxkjZ0L2atH+l0H/NeatWDAJs=
"
```

I am not sure how to remove that new line thingy. Anyone can advise?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link @cas but this is not what caused the issue.

Comment: Does whatever sends you the auth key add a line-feed or CR-LF?  or some non-essential verbosity. if so, try stripping them with sed or tr.  hmmm.. the  `=~` should handle that.  try adding printf debugging statements or run your script with `bash -x` to see what's going on.

Comment: Actually, looking at your =~ line again, I was right the first time.  The `(.*)` will capture everything to the end of the line, *including* the EOL marker (LF or CR-LF).  remove them with `... | tr -d '\r\n'`.

Comment: re: your updateL - when you echo that auth token, use `printf "%s" "$authKey" | sed -n l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by a newline or carriage-return and newline in $authKey, as supplied by "FireEye AX"

You can strip carriage returns and line feeds by piping it through `tr -d '\r\n'`

e.g.

```
# Get authentication key from FireEye AX response
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ ^SOME-PATTERN:[[:space:]](.*) ]]
    then
        authKey="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        authKey=$(printf "%s" "$authKey" | tr -d '\r\n')
    fi
done <auth.txt
```

I can't remember if $BASH_REMATCH will be passed to a subshell...you could try it in one line instead, maybe it will work:

```
authKey=$(printf "%s" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" | tr -d '\r\n')
```

Comment: I used something similar to solve. My exact code can be seen in the following. Code: authKey=$(echo $line | tr -d '\r\n')

Comment: glad to hear it worked for you.  BTW, `printf "%s" "$line"` is safer because a) the variable is properly quoted, and b) `echo` will interpret some string sequences (e.g. `\t`, `\n`) and change the output, while using `printf "%s"` will not.  you have no control over the value of the auth token received so have no way to ensure that those sequences won't be in the string.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and teaches me which method is a better one!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the data file you have been provided has Windows-style line endings (CR/LF) rather than Unix/Linux line endings (LF).

This alternative pattern match will exclude any possible trailing CR:

```
[[ $line =~ ^SOME-PATTERN:[[:space:]](([^\015]*) ]]
authKey="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```